# How to ysort Sprite3D properly in Godot 3D

Tags: godot

How can one apply a similar effect to ysort in Godot2D but using 3D.

[image]

I have the camera setup like this but when I add 2 Sprite3D it looks like this

[image]

If I increase the Y by 0.0001 on the character sprite, it appears in front of the portal. I was wondering though if there was a node that does this automatically. As increasing the Y makes the character fly up, so for example doing Y + 1, when panning the camera the position of the character is way off.

Comment: Does setting the Sprite3D's *Alpha Cut* to *Opaque Pre-Pass* help?

Comment: You could try changing the render priority in the materials.